# Turn off annoying mocha logs on Axios error

Tags: mocha.js, axios

I am testing my application and I noticed a thing that is annoying me. So my code is below. I am trying to register a user that is existing in database and asserting a failure.

```
async function registerUserAgain() {
  try {
    const { status } = await http.post(registrationUrl, user);
    assert.notStrictEqual(status, httpStatus.CREATED);
  } catch({ code, response }) {
    assert.strictEqual(response.status, httpStatus.CONFLICT);
  }
}

describe('Testing registration scenarios', function () {
  it('Duplicate user registration failure', registerUserAgain);
}
```

This code does exactly what I want. However when I look at the output

```
Request failed with status code 409 
    ✓ Duplicate user registration failure
```

How to remove this first line from the output? Logs would be prettier and cleaner if mocha and axios would not log those things.

Comment: That is an axios error. You should be able to add options to your request to change the status code range on what should reject with an error. Would also mean having to change your tests a bit.

Comment: wait up now... I know that it is axios error. It is completely okay that request is rejected with an error. I just want to prevent it from logging it to console. That logging happens only in mocha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like some bug thing in mocha. Updating it to `5.2.0` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command `$ mocha --reporter min test` or take a look at the other reporter options

Comment: Unfortunately this even made it worse. Now I ***only*** have unwanted messages, and good ones vanished :( And you have a typo you only need 2 dashes